# Oscillating Bar Based on Object Rotation (think Seesaw)?

Tags: drivers

I am trying to get a bar to pivot up and down based on the rotation of another object. For example, when a cube spins 360 degrees, the bar will rotate up and then down again for the duration of a full rotation - think: the movement of a seesaw. Therefore, a 180 degree rotation will move the bar up to it's maximum height and the next 180 degree continued rotation will move the bar down again. I have had success driving the Y rotation of the bar from the X rotation of the cube using a driver, but I can't get the bar to oscillate up and down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of wave-functions you could use, but the most obvious one is some multiple of

`sin( driver_object's angle )`

..especially if you're considering some kind of mechanical linkage.

Here, the planes's Z rotation is set to `sin( circle's Z rotation ) * whatever` ..

[image]

(and keyframes on the circle's rotation set to 'Linear', to loop):

[image]